# Android kotlin parser Gson Volley

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, android-volley

How can I access idClubLocal with Gson-Volley? I get the codCompeticion and the nomCompeticion but there is no way to do it to idClubLocal

[{"codCompeticion": "26",
"nomCompeticion": "Equipo",
"jornadas": [ {"idClubLocal": "xxxxx"....

FragJorActual

```
class FragJorActual : Fragment() {

    private val TAG = "MainActivity"   

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        retainInstance = true

        requestJsonObject()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_recycler, container, false)

        val miTexto: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Grupo)
        miTexto.setText(R.string.list_juveniles)

        return view
    }

    private fun requestJsonObject() {    

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)
        val url = "mi_url"

        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener { response ->

            val builder = GsonBuilder()
            val mGson = builder.create()

            var items: List<ModelArray> = ArrayList()
            items = Arrays.asList(*mGson.fromJson(response, Array<ModelArray>::class.java))


            recyclerView !!.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity!!, 1)

            val adapter = CalendarioAdapterArray(activity !!, items )
            recyclerView !!.adapter = adapter

        }, Response.ErrorListener { error -> Log.d(TAG, "Error " + error.message) })
        queue.add(stringRequest)
    }
}
```

CalendarioAdapterArray

```
class CalendarioAdapterArray(internal var context: Context, internal var jornadasList: List<ModelArray>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CalendarioAdapterArray.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.calendario_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val jornada = jornadasList[position]

        holder.textEquipoLocal.text = jornada.jornad.idClubLocal
        holder.textEquipoVisi.text = jornada.nomVisi
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = jornadasList.size

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        var textEquipoLocal: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_Equipo_Local) as TextView
        var textEquipoVisi: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_Equipo_Visitante) as TextView
    }
}
```

ModelArray

```
class ModelArray {

    @SerializedName("codCompeticion")
    @Expose
    var Local: String? = null

    @SerializedName("nomCompeticion")
    @Expose
    var nomVisi: String? = null

    @SerializedName("jornadas")
    @Expose
    var jornad: List<ModelList>? = null
}
```

ModelList

class ModelList {

```
@SerializedName("idClubLocal")
@Expose
var idClubLocal: String? = null

init {

    this.idClubLocal = idClubLocal
}
```

}

Comment: `jornad` is `List`. `jornada.jornad.get(0).idClubLocal` should work

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access a list neither to specify an index nor to iterate through them.

Iterate in any way, it's up to you:

```
jornada.jornad?.map { it.idClubLocal }
```

Access first index e.g.:

```
jornada.jornad?.first()?.idClubLocal
```

Comment: jornada.jornad?.first()?.idClubLocal only 1 register

Comment: But when all items?

Comment: As answered above: `jornada.jornad?.map { it.idClubLocal }` iterating is up to you how you want to handle it: concat, init new objects, etc, etc .There you can access all items in your list.

Comment: I do not know how to do it

Comment: e.g.: concat with comma: `jornada.jornad?.joinToString(", ") { it.idClubLocal }` As mentioned before, its up to you how to deal with list items.

Comment: I do not get it